# How should I store colors in JS?

Tags: javascript, opengl-es, webgl

The RGB colors are 0-255, so I can store a color (+alpha) in a uint8array(4), but if I want to use them in my webGL scene, then I have to divide them by 255 in every frame.

So which one is better? To store the colors in float32array instead of uint8array (4 times more memory), or convert the integer values to float at every frame?

Comment: It depends. Is your application running short of memory or of processing time?

Comment: I'm just asking. What does it depend?

Comment: Bergi is asking where your bottleneck is because that generally points to the "best" solution.  If you want to increase your framerate, store your data values as close as possible to their final usable state.  If you're looking to decrease your memory footprint, store your data values in the smallest necessary container. One other consideration: dividing by powers of 2 is very fast if that is the operation that is performed.  Is there any way that webGL can take a fixed-point value instead of a floating-point?   This effectively allows you to do faster integer math.

Comment: Dang it: http://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/specs/1.0/#6.12 No fixed-point calc.

Comment: Do I smell premature optimisation here?